# Change incoming stream name on runtime in wowza

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, stream, wowza

I have a question regarding changing of stream names in the incoming stream section.

I want the user to have a unique stream name everytime they stream so when I save them to my AWS bucket, the old streams don't get overwritten by the new ones.

For example: 
Incoming streams -> stream.mp4
stream.mp4 gets copied to S3 bucket.
When I stream again and go to the incoming streams section in wowza, I see stream.mp4 which will be saved to S3 bucket subsequently removing the previous file.

Is there a way I can control the stream name everytime I stream or would it be better to change the stream name in S3 bucket once it is copied.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are pushing the stream from the encoder to your Wowza server, as opposed to being pulled by your Wowza server, then the stream name is sent from the encoder. It would be best to configure unique stream names from the encoder side.

If you cannot control the stream names from the encoder side, you can also force unique live stream recordings in Wowza. You will need to enable versioning or the use of file version delegates to ensure that each streaming session will always have a unique stream recording name. If you are recording using the Wowza Streaming Engine Manager UI manually, then select the Version existing file option. The default file naming method is

```
${SourceStreamName}_${RecordingStartTime}_${SegmentNumber}
```

You can change this file template string from the Manager UI as well.